# Is this MySQL HA solution valid?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, high-availability

We are in the process of moving our MySQL DB from AWS RDS to EC2.

RDS provides us with with a solid HA solution, which we want to replicate in EC2. We've looked at MySQL Utilities and MHA, both of which present problems for us. As a result, we're thing about a DIY solution, which will work as follows:

We will have a Master and a Slave replica (Slave 1).
We will have a Slave replica of the Slave (Slave 2).

Master and Slave 1 will be behind a HA Proxy cluster.

We will monitor the Master very closely.

If the Master monitor detects a failure, we will run a script that shuts down the Master EC2 instance and stops the Slave process on the replica.

Slave 1 will now become the Master, and Slave 2 will become Slave 1. The new Slave 1 will be added to the HA Proxy cluster.

We will then rebuild Slave 2 from a backup of Master (backup every 3 hours).

We obviously need to be careful to ensure that all steps in the process exit cleanly, and that we have rock-solid error handling.

Can anyone offer an opinion as to the viability of our proposed DIY solution?

Comment: What's the purpose of HAProxy here, when you only have one writable master?  Why would slave 2 need to be rebuilt?  Slaves can be cascaded, and a failure of the master and/or making slave 1 writable should have **zero** implications for the data on slave 2.  If you **really** need rock solid HA, why mess around like this instead of using Galera Replication Provider and having multiple writable masters online all the time, or why not at least configure circular replication with the standby master set to read-only and have your automation toggle that?

Comment: Our MySQL DB is complex. Its hugely dependent on stored procs and temporary tables, so we want to stick with the RDS based HA solution that we know works. Hence, we want to stay with Master-Slave. HAProxy is in there for control purposes. It will only ever send traffic to the Master, until the Master fails, when we will stop the Slave and send traffic to the Slave (we are toying with the idea of doing this with DNS instead).

Comment: This is, of course, a valid use case for HAProxy -- I was just looking to clarify that you weren't imputing any capabilities to HAProxy that it doesn't have.  And, I think I just figured out what you meant by "rebuild slave 2" -- you mean rebuild a second slave, because you're implicitly changing the role of slave 2 to slave 1 so now there is no slave 2.  You aren't rebuilding the old slave 2, you're making a new one to perform the role of slave 2.

Comment: Correct. I've contacted AWS to ask exactly how they do HA in RDS.

Comment: DO NOT ATTEMPT to do failover in DNS unles you *really* know what you're doing (and that means master-master or multi-master with sticky sessions to the backend, and round-robin at the front).

Comment: I don't understand the alarmism in the comment. Why is a DNS solution so precarious? RDS High Availability is dependent on a DNS update. What we are proposing to do is 1. Detect Master failure 2. Stop Master EC2 instance 3. Stop Slave process 4. Update Route53 record for Master to point to Slave.

This is pretty much what happen in RDS. There is no need for sticky-sessions or round-robin or anything like that. We don't need atomic failover. Data process is our main business, so an interruption of 1-2 minutes isn't catastrophic.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are talking about asynchronous replication here....

While slave 1 needs to be configured to accept updates from the original master, configuring it as a master itself eliminates a step from your failover process.

Slave 2 should never be more than a few seconds behind the master - so why rebuild it from a backup which is hours behind?

Do you actually need the capacity of a 2 active + 1 passive node solution? Its adding a lot of complexity here? Does slave 2 currently do anything which can't be throttled in the event of the loss of master?

Or you could just go with multi-master replication.

Comment: The rebuild of Slave 2 refers to the rebuild of a totally new server. As part of the failover, Slave 1 has become Master, and Slave 2 has become Slave 1, so we have no Slave 2. Hence, we rebuild Slave 2.

Basically, what we're trying to do is replicate whatever RDS does, which is Master-Slave based.